# modal carousel is not working on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, carousel

i have this code and the modal carousel only shows the first pic

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Gallery</button>



                    <div class="modal fade  " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                          <!-- Indicators -->
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      </ol>
                          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                          <img  src="images/arredamenti1.png" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                          <img src="images/arredamenti2.png" alt="Second slide">

                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                          <img src="images/bg1.jpg" alt="Third slide">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                            <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control"  data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control"  data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                      </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
                          </div>
                        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

i have also loaded the libraries:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-modal-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal-carousel.js"/></script/>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

maybe it has some conflicts with other libraries ! 
when i click the button the modal appears, there is the first pic but indicators and controls are not working !

RESOLVED ... I just needed to change the data-target of indicators to #myModal
and add the same thing ( data-target #myModal ) to the controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this.....

```
<div class="modal fade  " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <div class="carousel slide" id="MyCarousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img  src="images/arredamenti1.png" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/arredamenti2.png" alt="Second slide">

                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/bg1.jpg" alt="Third slide">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Controls -->
                <a href="#MyCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
                <a href="#MyCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
            </button>
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Care to explain what the difference between the two is?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .MultiCarousel { float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 100%; position:relative; }
    .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner { transition: 1s ease all; float: left; }
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item { float: left;}
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { text-align: center; padding:10px; margin:10px; background:#f1f1f1; color:#666;}
    .MultiCarousel .leftLst, .MultiCarousel .rightLst { position:absolute; border-radius:50%;top:calc(50% - 20px); }
    .MultiCarousel .leftLst { left:0; }
    .MultiCarousel .rightLst { right:0; }

        .MultiCarousel .leftLst.over, .MultiCarousel .rightLst.over { pointer-events: none; background:#ccc; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
    var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
    var itemWidth = "";

    $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
        var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
        if (condition)
            click(0, this);
        else
            click(1, this)
    });

    ResCarouselSize();




    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResCarouselSize();
    });

    //this function define the size of the items
    function ResCarouselSize() {
        var incno = 0;
        var dataItems = ("data-items");
        var itemClass = ('.item');
        var id = 0;
        var btnParentSb = '';
        var itemsSplit = '';
        var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
        var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
        $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
            id = id + 1;
            var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
            btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
            itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);



                incno = itemsSplit[0];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;

            $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
            $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
            });

            $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
            $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

        });
    }


    //this function used to move the items
    function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
        var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
        var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
        var translateXval = '';
        var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
        var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
        if (e == 0) {
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = 0;
                $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = itemsCondition;
                $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
    }

    //It is used to get some elements from btn
    function click(ell, ee) {
        var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");
        var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
        ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
    }

});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
            <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>? 1</p>
                        <p>? 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>? 1</p>
                        <p>? 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>? 1</p>
                        <p>? 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>? 1</p>
                        <p>? 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>? 1</p>
                        <p>? 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary leftLst"><</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary rightLst">></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>







</body>
</html>
```